# UV project on object without the projection on the back of it

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, shaders, emission

I'm using a camera to reproject an image on a mesh using UVProject and a material with image texture + emission shader, and it appears that the image is also visible on the back of the object.

Do you know why and how to get rid of this projection on the back?

Many thanks[image: reprojected image]

Edit: below is my UV editor[image: UVeditor]

Blend file added [image]

Comment: Hi mooboots, here it is

Comment: Could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Okay, it's added

Comment: Oh OK i missed the UV Project thing, I'm not sure that you can avoid that, what were you trying to achieve exactly

Comment: I'm aiming at projecting multiples images from multiple point of view on the same object, using scripting. I have another camera for rendering the whole scene

Answer (score 0):

UV project basically makes a flattened version of your mesh from the camera's perspective. If you do not want the back parts of your mesh to feature that texture, you have to select these part and unwrap them again, and move them somewhere in your UV space that doesn't show the texture.

In your material, set your image texture's repeat mode to clip so that the picture isn't repeated.

Alternatively, create a new material slot, assign the back parts to that slot and put a completely different material in that slot.

Comment: Thanks for the precision! I'm aiming at projecting images on the same object (a more complicated one), using bpy scripting. Therefore is there a way to select the front or back parts automatically, then? Btw in the images I posted the "clip" mode is already on.